# Fail to install great expectation. Error : Cannot uninstall 'ruamel-yaml'

Tags: ruamel.yaml, great-expectations

When I was trying to install great_expectation on terminal,

'pip install great_expectations'

I got this error:

Installing collected packages: ruamel.yaml, jsonpatch, altair, great-expectations
Attempting uninstall: ruamel.yaml
Found existing installation: ruamel-yaml 0.15.87
ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'ruamel-yaml'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
any suggestions to solve this issue?
many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using conda or something similar non-standard, that is not fully pip compatible. You should make a virtualenv:

```
python -m venv /path/to/your/venv
source /path/to/your/venv/bin/activate  # adapt to your OS/shell
pip install great_expectations
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this using

`pip install great_expectations --ignore-installed ruamel.yaml`